# View worker / executor logs in Spark UI since 1.0.0+

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

In 0.9.0 to view worker logs it was simple, they where one click away from the spark ui home page.

Now (1.0.0+) I cannot find them.  Furthermore the Spark UI stops working when my job crashes! This is annoying, what is the point of a debugging tool that only works when your application does not need debugging.  According to http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Viewing-web-UI-after-fact-td12023.html I need to find out what my master-url is, but I don't how to, spark doesn't spit out this information at startup, all it says is:

```
... -Dspark.master=\"yarn-client\" ...
```

and obviously `http://yarn-client:8080` doesn't work. Some sites talk about how now in YARN finding logs has been super obfuscated - rather than just being on the UI, you have to login to the boxes to find them. Surely this is a massive regression and there has to be a simpler way??

How am I supposed to find out what the master URL is? How can I find my worker (now called executor) logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These answers document how to find them from command line or UI

[Where are logs in Spark on YARN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058663/where-is-sparks-log-if-run-on-yarn)

For UI, on an edge node

Look in /etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml for the yarn resource manager URI (`yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address`).

Or use command line:

```
yarn logs -applicationId [OPTIONS]
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your configuration of YARN NodeManager log aggregation, the spark job logs are aggregated automatically. Runtime log is usually be found in following ways:

**Spark Master Log**

If you're running with yarn-cluster, go to YARN Scheduler web UI. You can find the Spark Master log there. Job description page "log' button gives the content.

With yarn-client, the driver runs in your spark-submit command. Then what you see is the driver log, if log4j.properties is configured to output in stderr or stdout.

**Spark Executor Log**

Search for "executorHostname" in driver logs. See comments for more detail.

Comment: Please could you expand on "Search for "executorHostname" in driver logs.", suppose I find the hostnames for my executors, which I do know, how do I then view the logs???

Comment: Check the location : yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs: Determines where the container-logs are stored on the node when the containers are running. Default is ${yarn.log.dir}/userlogs. http://hortonworks.com/blog/simplifying-user-logs-management-and-access-in-yarn/

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that I can ssh into each box, find the actual files and read them.  I want to know how to read the logs in a web UI, just like I could in 0.9.0.  It seems like a major regression to make me ssh into boxes to find logs.

Comment: If yarn.nodemanager.log.log-dirs is under yarn.log.dir, then you read the log via NomeManager's web UI in the same way as you read NodeManager's log.

Comment: How do I find the "NomeManager's web UI" URL? I guess I just have to ask my DevOps team what they have configured it too right? Or is there a self service way to find out given one can ssh into the box?

Comment: Yes > ask my DevOps team