# Log4j not logging in spark yarn-cluster mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging, hadoop-yarn, log4j2

I have build a scala application and loggin with log4j.
Sample code:

```
logger.info(“This gets printed in client mode  but not in cluster mode”)
```

Issue is when i run in `yarn-client` mode above statements gets printed, but when I run `yarn-cluster` mode it doesn’t.

I want such messages to be printed in cluster mode as well.

Already tried

```
Spark-submit —files option
```

and setting `spark.executor.extrajavaoptions` and spark.driver.extrajavaoptions`

Comment: where do you want to have your statements printed? AFAIk they are printed on the driver (unless you log inside transformations/actions, in this case they are printed on the executors). If you switsch from yarn-client to yarn-cluster, the driver machine will change (in yarn-client, the machine where you submit the application is the driver, in yarn-cluster this is not the case)

Comment: Hi Raphael, Thanks. I want these statement to be printed on console or in a log file in cluster mode. How can that be done?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra: It should be available in the log file, you can access the log files using `yarn logs -applicationId <application ID>`

Comment: @AbhishekMishra : you can also look at the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058663/where-are-logs-in-spark-on-yarn question for more

Comment: Thanks Shankar. Can we redirect these yarn logs to a different file? Actually i want to generate these log at a specific location.