# How to handle log in Spark Cluster Mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, log4j, bigdata, hadoop2

I am new to Spark. I am not able to find out how to handle logs in Spark Cluster Mode. I have added the below properties in Spark script.

```
spark.conf.set("yarn.log-aggregation-enable","true")
spark.conf.set("yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs","HDFS_LOCATION")
spark.conf.set("yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir","HDFS_LOCATION")
spark.conf.set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.eventLog.dir", "HDFS_LOCATION")
spark.conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
```

And when runnig the spark-submit I am adding the below option:

`--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.debug=true -Dlog4j.configuration=$LOCATION/log4j.properties"`

But I am getting the below exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application
```

And I am unable to find any log in HDFS log location.

Please help as I am stuck with the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26082707/5019163