# How to get Log Aggregation in code by yarnClient

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm following this example about create YarnApp by java API.

https://github.com/hortonworks/simple-yarn-app

Works fine, but, the log exists only execution, after it the log gone.

How I can caught this by code ? or maybe enable one option?

Comment: Can you explain your cluster setup and post the output of `jps`?

Comment: I'm using distribution cloudera 6.3.1. I'm not administrator environment, but I checked in all nodemanager that the log are in /data01/yarn/container-logs/

Comment: Check whether `JobHistoryServer` is running?

Comment: Yes, ResourceManager and JobHistoryServer in the same machine.

Comment: Are you able to access the JobHistoryServer UI? Can you see the application logs in there? Or try `yarn logs -applicationId <appID>`.

Comment: I'm already try to run this code, but didn't find the logs. I'm checked yarn-site.xml, and  I found the path log on hdfs -> /tmp/logs/user/logs/<appID>, but isn't there. In this path there is only SPARK jobs.

Comment: Okay, post your `yarn-site.xml` and `mapred-site.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

You can find logs using LogCliHelpers by application id after application had finished:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.ApplicationId;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.ApplicationSubmissionContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.YarnClientApplication;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.YarnConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException;
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.logaggregation.LogCLIHelpers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public static void getLogs(YarnConfiguration conf, YarnClientApplication app) throws IOException, YarnException {
    ApplicationSubmissionContext appContext =
            app.getApplicationSubmissionContext();
    ApplicationId appId = appContext.getApplicationId();
    LogCLIHelpers logCLIHelpers = new LogCLIHelpers();
    logCLIHelpers.setConf(conf);
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    Path logFile = new Path("/path/to/log/file.log");
    fs.create(logFile, false);
    try (PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(logFile.toString())) {
      logCLIHelpers.dumpAllContainersLogs(appId, UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser().getShortUserName(), printStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tks Boris for your answer. I'm using the API version 3.0.0. This class changes a lot. Actually it's logCLIHelpers.dumpAllContainersLogs(ContainerLogsRequest arg0). I'm not understand when write the log to hdfs.

Comment: @Alan Sorry, I can't update my code now and yes, it's use API 2.2.0. maybe you can find answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058663/where-are-logs-in-spark-on-yarn