# Getting all logs of crashed Spark Yarn Job

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am submitting a (Scala/Java) job to a Spark cluster while including the following option on the spark-submit command:

```
--conf spark.yarn.log-aggregation-enable=true
```

I would hope that worker logs would be and remain available from/on the master with that option turned on, even when running time was short as in my case. However, when I `yarn logs` for my submitted application after it has crashed I am getting:

> Log aggregation has not completed or is not enabled

My submitted job consistently crashes early on, which is why I wish to to view all worker logs in the first place (the output from the `spark-submit` alone does not seem to flush *all* logged messages before giving a stack trace of the crashing error, hence the motivation).

- Should I do or configure anything more than specify that yarn option on the submit command to get the aggregation working as expected?
- Would there by any alternative way for quickly seeing the full logs of the workers other than separately logging into each and every worker and looking for its log directories?

Comment: Small note: my application crashes due to its own code; as far as Spark/Yarn are concerned it is validly FINISHED and SUCCEEDED as per the output from `yarn application -list` ... I am just not seeing logging messages that should come out before the application exception which crashes my job, so I figure they might be present in the worker log/s.

Comment: take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058663/where-are-logs-in-spark-on-yarn